# Which distributions $X$ have the property such that the expectation of the sum of $X$ and a constant is linear through the expectation of $X$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a normal distribution $Y \sim N\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)$, it is the case that

$$
E[Y+c] = E[Y] + c = \mu+c
$$

I am wondering which families of distributions generally fulfill this. For example, if $B \sim Beta(a,b)$, it is generally not the case that $E[B+c] = E[B]+c$. I am specifically interested in distributions with support $\Theta=[0,1]$ or $\{0,1\}$ (outside the uniform). Do general families exist for such a characterization?

Comment: Always true. This just a basic property of expectation.

Comment: Expectation is linear

Comment: It is always true for every random variable.  The thing is, if you add a constant to a beta distribution, it is no longer a beta distribution.  Maybe that was your confusion.

Comment: There is something fishy here.  For each & every r.v. $X$ for which $E[X]$ exists, it is true that $E[X+c]=E[X]+c$, for each constant $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always true.

As a proof, in continuous case we have

$$\mathbb{E}[Y+C]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(y+C)f_Y(y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}yf_Y(y)dy+C\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_Y(y)dy=\mathbb{E}[Y]+C\times 1$$